# Is there a simple way to generate bitmaps with a gradient using Python?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, graphviz

I am producing a simple, Python-based program that produces graphviz graphs as output.  I would like to use custom nodes that depict data from the program.  Using custom nodes is simple enough once you have the image, but I am having trouble figuring out a convenient method of producing the images I want.

Specifically, I would like the nodes to be circles whose area represents a measured value but with a gradient that represents the uncertainty in that value.  It seems reasonable to use a contour map produced with some math program (e.g. [sagemath](http://www.sagemath.org/)) but these tend to make square images that are not scaled.  Alternatively, the gradient functions on image manipulation programs seem difficult to relate to a rigorous gaussian function.

Ideally, I would like to write a function along the lines of this pseudocode...

```
def make_node_image(measured_value, std_dev):

    mean_circle_radius = sqrt(measured_value/pi)
    image_circle_radius = sqrt((measured_value + 2*std_dev)/pi)

    gradient_amplitude = 1/(std_dev*sqrt(2*pi))
    gradient_fade = e^(-(r-mean_circle_radius)^2/(2*std_dev^2))

    image_gradient = gradient_amplitude*gradient_fade

    ***generate_image_from_gradient***

    ***scale_and_clip_image_to_image_circle_radius***

    return image
```

The two starred bits are where I need help; I'd appreciate any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: I provided an answer below, but I didn't get the point of the parameter `coverage` and what did you expect to happen for values of `r` less than `mean_circle_radius`. With out understanding these points, I may have missed the final result, but I think I got the gist of what you were hoping for.

Comment: You are very observant.  The coverage parameter was originally intended to bound the image radius, but it was easier to just make cut off the boundary at two standard deviations.  The measured value is the mass of an object, so it can't be negative.  The probability distribution function of a mass measurement isn't strictly gaussian, but it's not a big enough deal to necessitate addressing in this program.  The "tail" of the density function below zero can be addressed in several ways, but it doesn't matter for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is with `matplotlib`, as you suggested in your tags. To do this, I would

1. use numpy to create an NxN array to represent `image_gradient`.
2. create a `figure` that has a square shape with size in inches correlated to the radius of your circle (`image_circle_radius`), for which you'll need to keep in mind the figure's dots-per-inch (`fig.dpi`)
3. create an `axes` with no margins, no frame and no ticks (`fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1],frameon=False, xticks=[], yticks=[]`)
4. use `imshow` to plot the array as an image.
5. create a circle, with center and radius in units of DPI
6. use the `set_clip_path()` method to clip the `AxesImage` created by the `imshow` call.

This approach is inspired by a [matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/clippath_demo.html).

Here is an attempt at doing what prescribe:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as path
import matplotlib.patches as patches

pi = np.pi
sqrt = np.sqrt
exp = np.exp

def make_node_image(measured_value, std_dev, coverage="0.96",imageID=1):

    DPI = 100
    TODPI=1
    MINSIZE = 50 # in DPI
    MAXSIZE = 400 # in DPI
    MAXAMPLITUDE = .005

    # make radius,std_dev  values in grid units
    mean_circle_radius = int(sqrt(measured_value/pi)/TODPI)
    image_circle_radius = int(sqrt((measured_value + 2*std_dev)/pi)/TODPI)
    if image_circle_radius < MINSIZE:
        raise Exception("image_circle_radius too small!")
    if image_circle_radius > MAXSIZE:
        raise Exception("image_circle_radius too large!")

    grid_std_dev = std_dev/TODPI

    gradient_amplitude = 1/(std_dev*sqrt(2*pi))/MAXAMPLITUDE
    gradient_fade = np.zeros([2*image_circle_radius,
                              2*image_circle_radius])
    for ix in range(2*image_circle_radius):
        for iy in range(2*image_circle_radius):
            r = sqrt((ix-image_circle_radius)**2
                     +(iy-image_circle_radius)**2)
            gradient_fade[ix,iy] = exp(
                -(r-mean_circle_radius)**2
                 /(2*grid_std_dev**2))

    image_gradient = gradient_amplitude*gradient_fade

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2*image_circle_radius/DPI,
                              2*image_circle_radius/DPI),dpi=DPI)


    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1],frameon=True, xticks=[], yticks=[])

    #***generate_image_from_gradient***
    im = ax.imshow(image_gradient,vmin=0,vmax=1)

    patch = patches.Circle((image_circle_radius,image_circle_radius), 
                           radius=image_circle_radius,fc='white')

    #***scale_and_clip_image_to_image_circle_radius***
    im.set_clip_path(patch)

    name = 'circImage%d.png'%imageID
    fig.savefig(name)

    return name

make_node_image(90000*pi,100)
```

This results in:

[image]

1. The circle seems to be clipped at the edges.
2. The is almost certainly vectorized approach to build `gradient_fade`, though off hand I don't know what it is.
3. This feels kludgy, and I really hope someone provides a more elegant answer.
4. Obviously the above code is just a starting point and someone can definitely improve upon it.

Comment: That's a great start, thanks!  I have used matploblib some, but mostly as a backend to python(x,y) and I'm not very good with using it directly.